# React Native elevation StyleSheet not working in FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, android-elevation

I'm trying to style my renderItem in FlatList but elevation not working properly. Is there anything I'm wrong or this is a React Native issue?

I tested ListView too but it still not working properly

This is TodoItem component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 10,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.4,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 3,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        marginBottom: 12
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: '#080808'
    }
})

export default class TodoItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}> {this.props.text} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And this is where I call it in FlatList

```
<FlatList
    data={this.props.items}
    renderItem={(item) => <TodoItem key={item.index} text={item.item} />}
/>
```

The point is that elevation works properly if I don't use FlatList like this

```
<TodoItem text="Hello world" />
```

[What I excepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWuH1.png)
[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTyDO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most issues like this are caused by styling that is applied to your surrounding view or the row that you are trying to render.

If you add a `marginHorizontal: 10` to the `styles.container` for the row that should probably do it for you.

Here is a simplified example where the edges of the row are not cut off. It has a couple of tweaks to make it work, using `state.items` instead of `props.items` and changing the style name for the TodoItem to `itemContainer`. It should give you an idea of how to implement it.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: [
      'Hello'
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.items}
          renderItem={(item) => <TodoItem key={item.index} text={item.item} />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.text}> {this.props.text} </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight + 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  itemContainer: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 3,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    marginBottom: 12
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#080808'
  }
});
```

Here is a snack showing it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/flatlist-with-elevation-on-rows